# Python command np.sum(x, axis=0) and softmax function

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following problem: I want to compute the softmax function in Python and get an unexpected result. The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np

def softmax(x):
    """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
    return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0)
```

It works perfectly but I don´t know why: It works on matrices as follows: If I insert a 2x2 matrix A, the output is yet another 2x2 matrix. Why is that? Shouldn´t it return a differently sized array since every element of the matrix, i.e. $x=A[0,0]$, yields 2 output values (namely $exp(x)/(exp(A[0,0])+exp(A[1,0]))$ and $exp(x)/(exp(A[0,1])+exp(A[1,1]))$, because or the axis=0 command? That would lead to an 8-element output array, but the actual result only has 4 elements. Also, how exactly does the axis=0 command work? If I type A=np.array([2, 4]), then the logical result of np.sum(A, axis=0) should be array([2, 4]), since the columns are summed up. But the result is array([6]). And the command np.sum(A, axis=1) strangely yields "'axis' entry is out of bounds", although the result should be array([6]) since the rows are summed up. Maybe my two problems are linked.
Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks,
Leon

Comment: Questions asking for debugging help should include a [mcve]. Please include the inputs + expected outputs vs. actual outputs.

Comment: Your intuition on `np.sum` works if you consider the `np.array([[2], [4]])` and use `axis=1`.

Answer (score 2):

I will jump into the "final" problem:

```
matrix_22 / vector_2
```

Because that does not make mathematical sense, numpy uses a certain assumption. Just as:

```
matrix_22 * 5
```

what that does is multiplying each element of the matrix by 5. Then if we consider a `matrix_22` as a vector of vectors, then the result of the `matrix_22 / vector_2` results on applying the operation division for each vector on the matrix.

You can easily check that behaviour executing the following:

```
np.array([[14, 28], [70, 56]]) / np.array([2, 7])
```

---

Notation: `matrix_22` is "some variable which contains a numpy array of shape 2x2, so it is a 2x2 matrix". And `vector_2` is a numpy array of two elements.